# Sorting a DataFrame by multiple columns while customizing the sorting order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame data with multiple columns: 'A', 'B', and 'C'. I want to sort this DataFrame first by column 'A' in ascending order, then by column 'B' in descending order, and finally by column 'C' in ascending order.

I've tried using data.sort_values() with a list of columns but couldn't get the desired sorting order for columns 'A' and 'B'. How can I achieve this customized sorting order using Pandas?

Comment: `df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'C'], ascending=[True, False, True])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B', 'C'], ascending=[True, True, True])

Hope it will help you

you can also change the ascending value as you preference

Comment: Really appreciate for your help! Indeed it wasn't hard.